# PHP Twitter API Multiple Requests Without Re Authorizing

Tags: php, twitter

I have the below code to allow users of my website to login via Twitter which works fine and displays there screen name when returning to the site after authorizing.

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'twitteroauth/autoload.php';
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
define('CONSUMER_KEY', '');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', '');
define('OAUTH_CALLBACK', '');
if (!isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
    $request_token = $connection->oauth('oauth/request_token', array('oauth_callback' => OAUTH_CALLBACK));
    $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];
    $url = $connection->url('oauth/authorize', array('oauth_token' =>     $request_token['oauth_token']));
    echo $url;
} else {
    $access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
    $user = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");
    echo $user->screen_name;
}
```

However, when refreshing the page the screen name is gone and i have to authorize with Twitter once again due to the one time auth token.

There is websites such as Twiends where you login via Twitter and then can follow other people to earn points. This obviously makes more than 1 request to Twitter as you can follow multiple people to earn more coins but you only have to login and authorize twitter once. How do websites like this re use the token?

Any help will be much appriciated thank you.